# Make 10 random changes in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a DNA string with length=100. I need to change 20 characters from that string randomly to a list of other characters.

```
import random

bases = ("A", "C", "G", "T")

def random_dna(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(bases) for _ in range(length))

randomDNA = random_dna(100)
new_list = ("1", "2", "3")

def change_random_string(randomDNA):
   x = random.randrange(0, len(randomDNA)-1)
val = random.choice(new_list)
return ''.join(randomDNA)
```

The problem is that my second method does not work at all. 
Expected output:

```
GTAAGCGCGTTGGGTTTGAAAGCCCACCGCAAAATGAAGCTCTAAGCAAACTGGGA
1T23GC1CGTTGGGTTTG1A2GCCCAC2GtAAAATGAAG11CTAAGCAAACTGGGA
```

Comment: You are using `randrange` which will return an integer. You can use `random.choices(randomDNA, k=20)`. Your new list and bases may be better in a list `bases = []`. Your new list contains integers also, is this on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an error of copy and paste, but your "return" is out of the function change_random_string().

I've changed the order of the lines:

```
import random

bases = ("A", "C", "G", "T")

def random_dna(length):
   return ''.join(random.choice(bases) for _ in range(length))

def change_random_string(randomDNA):
  x = random.randrange(0, len(randomDNA)-1)
  val = random.choice(new_list)
  return ''.join(randomDNA)  

 randomDNA = random_dna(100)
```

Then:

```
 print(randomDNA)
```

And the output looks like you've asked for:
 TTTATAGCTCAGCAACAAAACACTCCTCCATAACCGCTTCCTTGAACCTAATCGGCCCTAGCCACTCGTCTGGAGACGTTGGTATAGACTCCTGGGCGGT

And when mixing the bases up with the newlist:

```
bases = ("A", "C", "G", "T","1","2","3")
```

The same calling for print(randomDNA) returns:

2TAT1A3T2C1ATAC1A2GT3ACACTTCG23GATC3TCCC33AGA2ATAC3A311A2A1A1GACG2CT3GG1T3C13A1231AA122AA2133ACA1A3A

What was exactly the problem you've found?